# Alamofire 3 built fails when converting to swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

i am a newbie following an apparently outdated tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial). So i am trying to convert it to swift 2/alamofire 3.
I have the first two build runs going, but the last convert doesn't work. I am getting

Five100px.swift:21:45: Use of undeclared type 'GenericResponseSerializer'

[image]

Do i need to declare GenericResponseSerializer or do i need to install AlamofireImage as well for handling the image?

[edit] i have add this struc

```
struct GenericResponseSerializer<T> : ResponseSerializer {
    typealias SerializedObject = T
    var serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> Result<T>
    init(serializeResponse: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, NSData?) -> Result<T>)
}
```

but Result wants two parameters?
Five100px.swift:68:76: Generic type 'Result' specialized with too few type parameters (got 1, but expected 2)

Edit
In general which are the major changes to going from swift 1.2->2.0 and alamofire 2 ->3.0

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the updated README along with the Migration Guides we've put together. They document the exact issues you are running into.

- [3.0 README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/3.0.0-beta.3)
- [2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)
- [3.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Cheers.